# Two constexpr ceil functions

Tags: c++, c++20, constant-expression

ceil_constexpr is is based on: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8377412/ceil-function-how-can-we-implement-it-ourselves/8378022#8378022

ceil_constexpr2 is a simpler version that takes advantage of truncation.

WARNING 1: Both ceil functions uses  from c++20.

WARNING 2: ceil_constexpr uses bit_cast - a c++20 function that I believe only MSVC v14.27 supports at the current date, 20th August 2020.

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <concepts>
#include <limits>
#include <bit>
#include <exception>

template<typename T>
concept FloatingPoint =
    std::is_floating_point_v<T> &&
    (sizeof(T) == 4 || sizeof(T) == 8) &&//Only 32/64 bit allowed. 80 bit fp not allowed
    sizeof(float) == 4 && sizeof(double) == 8 &&//float must be 32 bit fp while double must be 64 bit fp
    std::numeric_limits<T>::is_iec559 == true &&// Only IEEE 754 fp allowed
    std::endian::native == std::endian::little;

template<FloatingPoint T>
constexpr bool isInf_constexpr(T inFp)//detect if infinity or -infinity
{
    constexpr bool is_T_Float = std::is_same_v<T, float>;
    using uintN_t = std::conditional_t<is_T_Float, uint32_t, uint64_t>;
    using intN_t = std::conditional_t<is_T_Float, int32_t, int64_t>;

    constexpr uintN_t mantissaBitNumber = is_T_Float ? 23 : 52;
    constexpr uintN_t infinityExponentValue = is_T_Float ? 0xff : 0x7ff; //the value of the exponent if infinity
    constexpr uintN_t positiveInfinityValue = infinityExponentValue << mantissaBitNumber;//the value of positive infinity
    constexpr uintN_t signRemovalMask = std::numeric_limits<intN_t>::max();//the max value of a signed int is all bits set to one except sign

    return ((std::bit_cast<uintN_t, T>(inFp) & signRemovalMask) == positiveInfinityValue);//remove sign before comparing against positive infinity value
}

template<FloatingPoint T>
constexpr bool isNaN_constexpr(T inFp)
{
    constexpr bool is_T_Float = std::is_same_v<T, float>;
    using uintN_t = std::conditional_t<is_T_Float, uint32_t, uint64_t>;
    using intN_t = std::conditional_t<is_T_Float, int32_t, int64_t>;

    constexpr uintN_t mantissaBitNumber = is_T_Float ? 23 : 52;
    constexpr uintN_t NaNExponentValue = is_T_Float ? 0xff : 0x7ff;//the value of the exponent if NaN
    constexpr uintN_t signRemovalMask = std::numeric_limits<intN_t>::max();//the max value of a signed int is all bits set to one except sign
    constexpr uintN_t exponentMask = NaNExponentValue << mantissaBitNumber;
    constexpr uintN_t mantissaMask = (~exponentMask) & signRemovalMask;//the bits of the mantissa are 1's, sign and exponent 0's.

    return ( 
        ((std::bit_cast<uintN_t, T>(inFp) & exponentMask) == exponentMask) &&//if exponent is all 1's
        ((std::bit_cast<uintN_t, T>(inFp) & mantissaMask) != 0) //if mantissa is != 0
        );

}

template<FloatingPoint T>
constexpr T ceil_constexpr(T inFp)
{
    if (isInf_constexpr<T>(inFp))
    {
        throw std::invalid_argument("Input floating point is infinity.");
    }
    else if (isNaN_constexpr<T>(inFp))
    {
        throw std::invalid_argument("Input floating point is NaN.");
    }

    constexpr bool is_T_Float = std::is_same_v<T, float>;
    
    constexpr uint32_t mantissaBitNumber = is_T_Float ? 23 : 52;
    constexpr uint32_t exponentMask = is_T_Float ? 255 : 2047;//used to remove the sign bit after the exponent bits
    constexpr uint32_t exponentBias = is_T_Float ? 127 : 1023;

    using uintN_t = std::conditional_t<is_T_Float, uint32_t, uint64_t>;
    using intN_t = std::conditional_t<is_T_Float, int32_t, int64_t>;


    const uintN_t input = std::bit_cast<uintN_t, T>(inFp);//bitwise copy floating point to unsigned integer

    const intN_t exponent = static_cast<intN_t>((input >> mantissaBitNumber) & exponentMask) - exponentBias;
    if (exponent < 0)
    {
        return (inFp > 0);
    }
    // small numbers get rounded to 0 or 1, depending on their sign

    const intN_t fractional_bits = static_cast<intN_t>(mantissaBitNumber) - exponent;
    if (fractional_bits <= 0)
    {
        return inFp;
    }
    // numbers without fractional bits are mapped to themselves

    
    //constexpr uintN_t uIntAllOnes = is_T_Float ? 0xffffffff : 0xffffffffffffffff;
    constexpr uintN_t uIntAllOnes = std::numeric_limits<uintN_t>::max();//store the max value of an unsigned integer (all bits are 1's)

    const uintN_t integral_mask = uIntAllOnes << fractional_bits;
    const uintN_t output = input & integral_mask;
    // round the number down by masking out the fractional bits


    inFp = std::bit_cast<T, uintN_t>(output);//bitwise copy unsigned integer to floating point

    if (inFp > 0 && output != input)
    {
        ++inFp;
    }
    // positive numbers need to be rounded up, not down


    return inFp;
}//algorithm from: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8377412/ceil-function-how-can-we-implement-it-ourselves/8378022#8378022

template<FloatingPoint T>
constexpr T ceil_constexpr2(const T inFp)//simpler version
{
    if (isInf_constexpr<T>(inFp))
    {
        throw std::invalid_argument("Input floating point is infinity.");
    }
    else if (isNaN_constexpr<T>(inFp))
    {
        throw std::invalid_argument("Input floating point is NaN.");
    }

    constexpr bool is_T_Float = std::is_same_v<T, float>;

    using uintN_t = std::conditional_t<is_T_Float, uint32_t, uint64_t>;
    using intN_t = std::conditional_t<is_T_Float, int32_t, int64_t>;

    if (inFp > 0 && inFp != static_cast<intN_t>(inFp))
    {
        return static_cast<intN_t>(inFp + 1);
    }
    else
    {
        return static_cast<intN_t>(inFp);
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to CodeReview@CR. And thanks for providing the reference for the algorithm/procedure.

Comment: @G. Sliepen I added a check for integral input values.

Answer (score 3):

You have misspelt the typenames from `<cstdint>` (they are all in the `std` namespace; it's a portability error to assume they are also in the global namespace).

Although probably only of theoretical interest, given the conditions imposed by the `FloatingPoint` concept, but the exact-width types are usually a bad choice - prefer `std::uint_fast64_t` and friends where extra width won't hurt.

I guess that throwing exceptions for infinities and NaNs is a valid design choice (I would prefer to return the value unchanged, like `std::ceil()` does on IEEE-754 platforms), but this behaviour should be clearly documented somewhere - probably at the start of the header file.